# Magento Rest API Issue When Using PayPal Payment Advanced

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento's Rest API to sell item from my Wordpress based site. I am having an issue when I try to use PayPal Payment Advanced to complete the transaction. Here is the code below:

```
$paymentArray = array(
    "method" => "payflow_advanced",
    'cc_cid' => $_POST['cccvv'],
    'cc_owner' => $_POST['firstName'] . " ". $_POST['lastName'],
    'cc_number' => $_POST['ccnumber'],
    //'cc_type' => "MC",
    'cc_exp_year' => $_POST['ccmonth'],
    'cc_exp_month' => $_POST['ccyear'],
);

$resultPaymentMethod = $client->call($session, 'cart_payment.method', array($shoppingCartIncrementId, $paymentArray));
```

When I run the code, it comes back as "true" but the api never hits PayPal and authorizes the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Once you var_dump($resultPaymentMethod) and see what's it displaying the output..